# PC doesn't start. Lights go on and it gets hot, but doens't show anyting

Tags: boot

I have a Dell Inspiron E1505. It runs on win 7.

This morning I tried to turn it on, lights flash and the power light keeps on like it is on. But it doesn't shows anything, neither the BIOS nor an error. It even gets hot, like its on, but nothing happens.

Help, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try hooking a monitor up to your laptop. If that works, the display cable is probably defective. A replacement will probably run about $20 on eBay, which might be worth it if you know someone who is comfortable working on laptops or if you're comfortable doing it yourself.

If the laptop really isn't booting, you could try removing the RAM to see if it will at least beep errors at you when you turn it on.

If it still doesn't do anything, your motherboard has probably failed. It's possible to get a replacement, but it would be cheaper in terms of time and money to just replace the entire laptop. You can buy a portable external hard drive enclosure in order to recover any data, and if you have time, you could sell the working components (including structural components that aren't cracked) on eBay.

If you decide to take it to a local computer shop for a more conclusive diagnosis, but keep in mind that you can get a refurbished laptop with comparable specs for $200 or less.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I'll try this things and see if it's fixable.

Comment: Best of luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your screen connector is broken, your screen itself or your motherboard(partially).

Comment: The thing is I don't hear the windows startup sound. May this be caused by that too?